# I keep on getting the error "TypeError: must be str, not bytes"

Tags: python, tkinter, smtplib

I am not new to python, but I am new to the Tkinter, and smtplib modules. I'm trying to set up my own email interface, using tkinter as the GUI, and smtplib to send the emails. The program takes the input from the entry boxes, then uses them to send the emails, but it keeps throwing this error and I don't know how to fix it...

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/Users/jonbrain/PycharmProjects/GUI for Email/venv/The 
Propper GuI.py", line 39, in send_it
server.login(emailUser, user_Password)


`File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/
python3. 6/smtplib.py", 
line 721, in login
initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/
python3.6/smtplib.py", line 631, in auth
(code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

I have done a bit of research; many people have the same question, but in an entirely different situation (which calls for a different fix). So here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib


root = Tk()
root.title("Jon's Email Service")
root.geometry("800x400+0+0")

Label(root, text="Jon's Email Service", font=("arial", 
60,"bold"), fg="blue").pack()

Label(root, text="User's Email address {Has to be gmail} ",font= 
("arial", 20,), fg="black").pack()

One = Entry(root,width=40, bg="white")
One.pack()

Label(root, text="User's Gmail Password", font=("arial", 
20,),fg="black").pack()

Two = Entry(root, width=40, bg="white")
Two.pack()

Label(root, text="Email Recipient", font=("arial", 
20,),fg="black").pack()
Three = Entry(root,width=40, bg="white")
Three.pack()
Label(root, text="The Message", font=("arial", 
20,),fg="black").pack()

Four = Entry(root, width=60, bg="white")
Four.pack()

def send_it():
    email_resipient = Three.get()
    Label(root, text="Email Is Sent!", font=("arial", 20,), 
    fg="Red").pack()
    emailUser = One.get()
    user_Password = Two.get
    msg = Four.get()
    print(emailUser)
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(emailUser, user_Password)
    server.sendmail(emailUser, email_resipient, msg)
    server.quit()

send = Button(root, text="Send", default='active', width = 40, 
bg = "lightblue",command = send_it).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you will find that `user_Password` isn't what you think.

Comment: user_ Password  is the variable I created, so that the users sign in credentials is not hard coded in.

Comment: `user_Password` isn't a string, but you're trying to use it like one. Add `print(user_Password)` to your code and you'll see it's not what you expect.

Comment: Ok, I added `print(user_Password)` and it returned exactly what I typed into the entry box. What are you getting at?

Comment: That is impossible. In the above code, `user_Password` is a _function_, not a string. You are setting `user_Password` to `Two.get`. `Two.get` is a function. You need to be setting `user_Password` to the _result_ of the function: `Two.get()`. Notice the trailing `()`.

Comment: Ok, the missing parentheses in `user_Password = Two.get` in the above code, was merely the mistake I was trying to find, and was pointed out to me in the answer of the above question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick look, I see this line -> `user_Password = Two.get` missing the brackets on the end of it.  As a result, the password is probably not being supplied, rather a bytes object which is not the password anyhow. 
changing the line to `user_Password = Two.get()` seems to work for me in my testing

That should resolve the issue the question asks about although you may possibly end up with a new issue `smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 196sm197509481pfc.77 - gsmtp')` which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The error that you brought up, is merely your google sign in not working, like your password does not match up with your email, or you got you password wrong.